# Set input variable when option is changed

Tags: angularjs

I have select option field and input type field:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <td>
  <select ng-init="loadUsernames()" ng-model="person.username" ng-options="item.staff_id as item.username for item in usernames" >
    <option value="">Select Username</option> 
  </select>
  </td>            
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.house" required=""></td>
</tr>
```

I use this to display my choice:

```
<div id="choicesDisplay">
  {{ persons }}
</div>
```

Ans js part `loadUsernames()` function:

```
$scope.loadUsernames = function(){
  $http.get("Unity/load_username.php")  
  .then(function(data){
    $scope.usernames = data.data;
    console.log(data);
  })  
}
```

Here is `load_username.php` file:

```
$loadUsernames = loadUsernames();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($loadUsernames)){  
  $output[] = $row;  
}  
echo json_encode($output);
```

In array I get this:

```
0:"1001037"
1:"AARONJAMES"
2:"1"
3:"U (Red)"
$$hashKey:"object:12"
fkhouseid:"1"
hname:"U (Red)"
staff_id:"1001037"
username:"AARONJAMES"
```

How can I set `ng-model="person.house"` to display `hname` and set value to `fkhouseid` after option is selected?

Comment: That's a lot of code to read that seems unrelated to your question. Can you make it minimal please? I did not get what you expect and the relation between your `select/option` and your `ng-model`.

Comment: @RaphaMex I edited the question. What i want is to change input field after option is selected. I get house name when I load users and I want to set value inside `ng-model="person.house"` when username is selected.

Comment: you can add a watcher on person.username.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following snippet: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xr82a1gL/)

What you need to do is to add ng-change directive to your select tag and add a function that will be executed when selection is changed. This method will fill your person object model and set the house property to the newly selected value. Something like the following:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<select ng-model="selectedUser.user" ng-options="user as user.username for user in usernames track by user.staff_id" ng-change="fillInput()"></select> 
<div ng-if="selectedUser.user">Full selected user info : {{ selectedUser.user | json}}</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="person.house" required="">
</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.person = {};

$scope.usernames = [{
  fkhouseid:"1",
  hname:"U (Red)",
  staff_id:"1001037",
  username:"AARONJAMES"
}, 
{
  fkhouseid:"2",
  hname:"Different house name",
  staff_id:"1001038",
  username:"James Aron"
 }];

$scope.selectedUser = {
  user:""
};

$scope.fillInput = function(){
    $scope.person.house = $scope.selectedUser.user.hname;
};
```

For more information about ng-change, please check out the following: [w3schools ng-change](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-change.asp)

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works if there is only one field. But I need to work with  `data-ng-repeat="person in persons"`. please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/xr82a1gL/3/

Comment: I'm actually not really sure what are you trying to accomplish with this. Could you please clarify your question a bit more, the snippet you sent is really confusing. What are you trying to do with the ng-repeat ?

Comment: I want to allow user add more than one user at the same time. And then submit it. That is why I use ng-repeat so user could add more users and submit it later. And what I want is to display house name after user is chosen

Comment: When user is added, is he only added to the dropdown ? like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf071nzt/
or do you need for some reason to add a whole new dropdown and input ?

Comment: Yes, i need whole new dropdown and input